# nextTick usage in classes

Tags: oop, node.js, coffeescript

If I have a code like this:

```
class SomeClass
  constructor: ->
    @someAttr = false

  someFunction: ->
    process.nextTick ->
      @someAttr = true

obj = new SomeClass
obj.someFunction()
obj.someAttr # Would still be false, because the @ (this) is in the process context
```

it won't work, because process.nextTick brings us into a different context, in which @someAttr isn't defined. How can I work around this (also when I want to call methods of SomeClass)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual way around this is to store a reference to `this` in a local variable which will be available within the anonymous function. In JavaScript:

```
function someFunction() {
  var self = this;
  process.nextTick(function() {
    self.someAttr = true;
  });
}
```

CoffeeScript has a special syntax to help with this; the "[fat arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow)":

```
class SomeClass:
  someFunction: ->
    process.nextTick =>
      @someAttr = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `=>` instead of `->` to preserve `this` variable.

```
class SomeClass
  constructor: =>
    @someAttr = false

  someFunction: ->
    process.nextTick =>
      @someAttr = true
```